# How to resolve lombok error "log cannot be resolved"?

Tags: spring-boot, lombok

I have errors in the project (springboot) with all code "log." I have followed the advise from the link below (in my case using eclipse with spring tools):

[enter link description here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/4934108555/)

I spent 2 hours delete the project and reopen, clean, build everything and nothing working. I also did mvn compile from command line and this seem to work fine, so it's clearly eclipse problem.

code from pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Eclipse ini file:
[image]

I run the jar (java application) and specify the ini file. The jar is added
to the eclispe directory but it has no  version on it.

Also lombok should appeared in the eclipse about screen and it's not.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install Lombok into your IDE? Do you have a Lombok dependency in your pom.xml?  and can you share a code snippet?

Comment: hi @Habil have a look now I hope to get clearer idea.

Comment: I don't use Eclipse but in Intellij I had to enable annotation processing in the settings. Maybe this is also the case for eclipse

Comment: I've tried in eclispe as well, oit doen't work

Comment: Try to install lombok plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this problem I had to use STS4 and the same indtallation
for eclpise is work for STS.
lombok is added to the about screen, all good now.